# HardCode MySQL Syntax issue

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a huge problem with `SELECT DISTINCT` values from one of my table.

Table 1 :`T1`

```
pid     box         cassette       seal      added (timestamp)
---------------------------------------------------------------
1       A1212       A01A00001     P123456    2015-01-01 12:00:01  
2       A1212       A01A00001     P123457    2015-01-01 12:00:01 
3       A1214       A01A00004     C123458    2015-01-01 12:00:01
4       A1214       A01B00005     D123459    2015-01-01 12:00:01
5       A1214       A01B00006     D123460    2015-01-01 12:00:01
6       A1212       A01B00007     E123461    2015-01-01 12:00:01    
7       A1212       A01B00007     E123462    2015-01-01 12:00:01
```

Table 2 :`T2`

```
id   t1_pid  box     cassette      seal     error    despatched 
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
1      3    A1214    A01A00004   C123458    false      true
2      7    A1212    A01B00007   E123462    true       false
```

I need to `SELECT` all `DISTINCT` every boxm,cassette,seal from `Table T1` which:
1. are NOT in `Table T2` and, most important - only with `seal` which pid is the highest / last added 
OR
2. are in `Table T2` but `T2.error=true` or `T2.despached=false`

Result Should leave `T1` records

1 - because record 2 has the same box, cassete but record 1 has lower `pid`

3 - because there is  `t2.t1_pid=3` but `despatched=TRUE`

6 - because record 7 has the same box, cassete but record 6 has lower `pid`

Record 7 should be in result because there is  `t2.t1_pid=7` but `error=TRUE`

RESULT TABLE:

```
id      box          cassette     seal
-------------------------------------------
2       A1212       A01A00001     P123457     /(rec. no 2)            
4       A1214       A01B00005     D123459     /(rec. no 4)       
5       A1214       A01B00006     D123460     /(rec. no 5)       
6       A1212       A01B00007     E123462     /(rec. no 6)
```

I've tried the following syntax which is OK if seal number is higher. I need to change the condition for `if t1.pid` is higher, but can't figure it out.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.pid, T1.box, T1.cassette, T1.seal 

FROM T1 INNER JOIN 
(SELECT T1.box, T1.cassette, max(T1.seal) as seal FROM  

T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 o ON T1.pid=o.t1_pid WHERE 
(o.id IS NULL or (o.despatched=0 )) 
GROUP BY T1.cassette, T1.box)  
as b using (cassette, box, seal)
```

Many thanks for your help and precious time

Comment: So if I find a record in t2 with error=true or despached=false, I don't care about the pid and it is allowed to have more than one result record thus for a box/cassette? And if I have two records for a box/casette and the one with the higher pid is in t2, then I don't show any of them, because one doesn't have the highest pid and the other is in t2? And where do the IDs in your results come from?

Comment: 1. It is not allowed to get in result more than one record of the same box and cassette.
2. "And if I have two records for a box/casette and the one with the higher pid is in t2, then I don't show any of them, because one doesn't have the highest pid and the other is in t2? " - Yes.
3. Result ID's are from `T1.pid`

Answer (score 1):

This task has nothing to do with DISTINCT, as we are not talking about duplicate records here we must eliminate. This is rather about aggregation (i.e. boiling down results to unique box/cassette data).

You named two conditions for T1 records:

1. are NOT in Table T2 and, most important - only with seal which pid is the highest / last added OR
2. are in Table T2 but T2.error=true or T2.despached=false

Condition 1:

```
where t1.pid not in (select t1_pid from t2)
and not exists
(
  select *
  from t1 as later
  where later.box = t1.box
  and later.cassette = t1.cassette
  and later.pid > t1.pid
)
```

Condition 2:

```
where t1.pid in
(
  select t1_pid 
  from t2
  where t2.error = true 
  or t2.despached = false
)
```

This doesn't suffice however, because we could still get more than one record for a box and casette (one match with condition 1 and one with condition 2 or multiple matches with condition 2). In your comments you add a third condition:

3. It is not allowed to get in result more than one record of the same box and cassette

Maybe you store your data such that a box/casette will always either be matched only once by the two conditions, but *technically* at least it is possible to get duplicates, so we should find a way to deal with it. The easiest is to group by box and casette, so as to ensure to get only one result record per box and casette. Then show the minimum or maximum matching seal with it.

```
select box, casette, max(seal)
from t1
where 
(
  t1.pid not in (select t1_pid from t2)
  and not exists
  (
    select *
    from t1 as later
    where later.box = t1.box
    and later.cassette = t1.cassette
    and later.pid > t1.pid
  )
)
or t1.pid in
(
  select t1_pid 
  from t2
  where t2.error = true 
  or t2.despached = false
)
group by box, casette;
```

I don't show the IDs in the result, because I have no idea how you get them. You say they are T1 IDs, but it's not the IDs of the selected records, e.g. you select record 2 (pid 2), but in your results you show the record with ID 1 for reasons I don't understand.

Comment: Than You for Your answer, I just don't understand why You prefer selecting max(seal) if It's possible the seal with higher ID / last added has the lower number . Your're right with my fault with result ID's - I've edited that.

Comment: I get records as per your condition 1. I also get records as per your condition 2. As I said it is technically possible that this gives you more than one record for a box/cassette. That you don't want such duplicates is a condition 3 you only added in your comments. You didn't specify which seal to choose in such a case. I thought it didn't matter, so I chose the maximum one. If it *does* matter which to choose, then you must specify the algorithm you want applied. But this would make all this even more complicated and I wonder if you are making things more complicated than they actually are.

Answer (score 0):

I've created following syntax which I think - works fine but I really don't if it's optimized for tables `T1`, `T2` with 1 bilion records

```
SELECT abc.pid, abc.box, abc.cassette, abc.seal FROM
  (
  SELECT tt.pid, tt.box, tt.cassette, tt.seal
  FROM t1 tt
    INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT box, MAX(pid) AS pid
      FROM t1 
      WHERE added>DATE(now() - INTERVAL 2 DAY) /* for example */
      GROUP BY box, cassette
    ) groupedtt       
    ON tt.box = groupedtt.box
  AND tt.pid = groupedtt.pid
  ORDER BY box,cassette
  ) abc
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 o ON abc.pid=o.pid
WHERE
  (
  o.pid IS NULL 
  or (
      o.despatched=0 AND
      o.added>DATE(NOW() -  INTERVAL 2 DAY) /* for example */
     )
  )
```

Comment: This doesn't match your description. Your query only gets boxes with the highest pid. But in your second condition you say you want t1 records which have a match in t2 with error=true or despached=false, no matter what pid. So either your query or your description is wrong. (The difference in the two conditions is after all the main point why my query got so complicated.) Moreover the join condition on tt/groupedtt seems incomplete (shouldn't they also have the same cassette?). And then I don't see you checking the error flag.

Comment: At last the query structure is strange. The order by in the subquery makes no sense. It has no effect - or at least it is not guaranteed to have any effect. And it is not necessary to subquery at all. Simply inner-join groupedtt and left-join t2. Then it is a bad style to use joins when you are merely looking for existence. Use EXISTS or IN instead to make your query more readable.